# Can we use Asynchronous method invocation inside a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I want to optimize Performance by using threading.

```
public delegate int DelegateGetMarkOfSubject(int subjectid, int studentid);

int TotalMark = 0;

public void GetTotalMark(int StudentId)    
{
    TotalMark = 0;

    List<Subjects> lstSubj = GetSubjectList(StudentId);
    Waithandle[] waitHandler = new waitHandler[10];

    DelegateGetMarkOfSubject delmarkOfSubj = new DelegateGetMarkOfSubject(GetMark);

    foreach(var subject in lstSubj)
    {
        IAsync result_subject.id = delmarkOfSubj.BeginInvoke(subject.id, StudentId, new AsyncCallBack(GetMarkComplete), null);
        waitHandler.add(result_subject.id.AsyncHandle);
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandler);
    return TotalMark;
}


GetMarkComplete(Iasynch argument)
{
    DelegateGetMarkOfSubject  del = (DelegateGetMarkOfSubject )((Asynchresult ar)).AsynDelegate;

    newMark = del.EndInvoke(argument)

    if(LockingCondition)
    {
        //PutLock

        TotalMark += newMark;

        //Release Lock
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm failing to see the question.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like a perfect fit for .Net 5... Await()!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use PLINQ?

```
class Subject
{
    public Int32 Mark { get; set; }
}

        var subjects = new List<Subject>
        {
            new Subject { Mark = 50 },
            new Subject { Mark = 75 },
            new Subject { Mark = 81 },
        };

        Console.WriteLine(subjects.AsParallel().Sum(subject => subject.Mark));
```

Comment: I was just about to add a very similar answer. PLINQ is pretty darn perfect. The OP could also consider using Rx (System.Reactive) as an alternative too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Reactive Framework (Rx) version of your code:

```
var totalMarks = (
    from subject in lstSubj.ToObservable()
    from mark in Observable.Start(() => GetMark(subject.id, StudentId))
    select mark).Sum().Last();
```

This produces the result in parallel too.